# insert data from two lists to dict with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I tried this:

```
numbers_dict = dict()
num_list = [1,2,3,4]
name_list = ["one","two","three","four"]
numbers_dict[name for name in name_list] = num for num in num_list
```

And as a result I got this exception:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
numbers_dict[name for name in name_list] = num for num in num_list
```

Comment: Do you need to handle the case where the lists differ in length?

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist no

Comment: Another option that's appropriate here: `{name: num for num, name in enumerate(name_list, 1)}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly loop. You can use zip to join your two lists and then wrap it in a dict for the result you're looking for:

```
>>> dict(zip(num_list, name_list))

{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to mix list comprehensions, `for` loops and multiple key access into a single expression. This, unfortunately, is not possible in Python. Choose one method and stick with it.

Here are some options. They all involve `zip`, which returns elements from each argument iterable sequentially.

#### for loop

```
d = {}
for k, v in zip(name_list, num_list):
    d[k] = v
```

#### dictionary comprehension

```
d = {k: v for k, v in zip(name_list, num_list)
```

#### dict constructor

```
d = dict(zip(name_list, num_list))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use zip - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip.

```
numbers_dict = dict()
num_list = [1,2,3,4]
name_list = ["one","two","three","four"]

numbers_dict = dict(zip(name_list, num_list))
```

then `print(numbers_dict)` gives `{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}`.

Answer (score 2):

You NEED to use the For Loop?
So just:

```
for i in range(len(num_list)):
    numbers_dict[num_list[i] = name_list[i]]
```

But the best tool you could use is `zip`:

`numbers_dict = zip(num_list, name_list)`

Comment: In this case also `num_list` can itself be expressed as `range(1, 5)`, simplifying your construct some.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I'm just complementing OP's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are comprehensions for `dict` as well as for `list`. The `dict` ones look like the literal syntax:

```
{key: value for key, value in iterable}
```

In your case `zip` is probably the right tool:

```
>>> num_list = range(1, 5)
>>> name_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>> zip(num_list, name_list)
[(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
>>> dict(_)
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pandas:

`numbers_series = pd.Series(name_list,index=num_list)`

A pandas series acts much like a dictionary, but if you really want it in dictionary form, you can do `numbers_dict = dict(numbers_series)`.

Comment: And you could use a thermonuclear device to kill mosquitoes. :) Pandas is fine when the OP is asking for a Pandas solution, or if they have a lot of data to process, but it's overkill when the OP just wants to turn a pair of small lists into a dict.